# jquery ui tabs navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui tabs..what i am trying to do is  from javascript i am trying to display the second tab after some event from tab1..I am using the following code to change to tab2 which actually is not happening..what ami doing wrong here

jquery:

```
   $(this.el).find("#ui-id-8").parent(".ui-state-default .ui-corner-top").attr({'tabindex':'0', 'aria-selected':'true'}).addClass("ui-tabs-active ui-state-active").show();
```

html

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="asociateconddiv" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true"><a href="#asociateconddiv" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Campaign Details</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="createconditiondiv" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false"><a href="#createconditiondiv" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Scenarios</a></li>
                   <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="assoctrulegroupdiv" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false"><a href="#assoctrulegroupdiv" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Confirm &amp; Run</a></li>
               </ul>
```

Comment: why dont u try this.$("#tabs").tabs("select", "#tabs-" + thisID); here thisID is the ID which ur newly opening the tab having.hopefully this is correct if i understand the question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set active tab in jquery ui tabs as below:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({active: 1});
```

**Active** takes value as zero based.

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/pS3PW/)

Also check detail [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)